# Connecting to the NEST directly

Tags: python, linux, nest-api

I would like to connect (and subsequently control) the NEST thermostat directly as opposed to having go through the NEST servers. In other words,  I have a NEST thermostat connected to my wifi, I have my linux machine at home also connected to the same router, and I want the linux box to talk to the NEST. Possible?

I used to have a Radio Thermostat 3M-50. They provided a JSON based API. I could do something like this -

```
$ curl http://thermostat1/tstat
{"temp":67.50,"tmode":1,"fmode":0,"override":0,"hold":0,
"t_heat":62.00,"time""{"day":1,"hour":9,"minute":47},
"t_type_post":0}
```

I have a Belkin WeMo switch. I use Python's requests module to post to

```
http://IP_address_wireless_switch:49153/upnp/control/basicevent1
```

And I can control by setting the binary state as a part of the headers via SOAP.

I want to be able to do something similar with the NEST. Is that doable? Do I *have* to use only their servers, and rely on their servers being up and rely on my home having a working internet connection? (If there's an outage for instance, do I lose the ability to control my thermostat remotely?)

Answer (score 2):

The Nest API is only available as a cloud API. They have rate-limiting that protects the batteries on the thermostat. (even with a c-wire you can drain the battery pretty quickly and cause the unit to heat up, throwing off sensors, if you call it too often)

You might want to checkout the [Thread Group](http://www.threadgroup.org/) which Nest co-founded to solve local device communication.